# Ruby keyword arguments clarification

Tags: ruby, keyword-argument

Lately I saw this function signature:

```
   class Foo < Bar
    def initialize(arg: {})
      ...
   end
```

What does the keyword argument (`arg: {}` ) with the curly braces means here?

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question so it should not have a Rails tag.

Comment: I removed ruby on rails tag because as Cary said, this is purely ruby question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just a keyword argument with an empty hash as the default value:

```
def initialize(arg: {})
  arg
end

irb(main):011:0> initialize().class
=> Hash
```

Its really strange and unidiomatic though. Before Ruby 2.0 introduced first-class support for keywords you declared a method that takes an optional options hash as:

```
def initialize(hash = {})

end
```

This argument had to be at the end of the list of. The name is not significant.

With Ruby 2.0 you can declare a method that takes any number of keywords with a double splat:

```
def initialize(**other_keyword_args)

end
```

You can combine it with positional and named keyword arguments as well:

```
def initialize(a, b = 2, foo:, bar: 2, **other_keyword_args)

end
```

Using `initialize(arg: {}, ...)` would make sense if there where more parameters and this one takes a hash but on its own its just strange.

Comment: I cannot really understand why it doesn't make sense to use it. It's just another way of using the double splat, right? Maybe it could be used for more clarity? But again this is subjective

Comment: It is NOT equivalent to a double splat or `hash = {}`.  You have to actually call it like `initialize(arg: { foo: 'bar' })`. If you call `initialize(foo: 'bar')` you'll get `ArgumentError (unknown keyword: foo)`. Thats why it would make more sense if it was part of a complex signature but not on its own.

Comment: It also does not guarantee that arg is a hash. The user can pass whatever they want. If you use `**kwargs` - `kwargs` is always a hash.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby doesn't need braces (`{}`) around a hash when passing the last argument to a method:

```
def foo(anything)
  anything       # => {:arg=>{}}
          .class # => Hash
end

foo(arg: {})
```

For more information see "[Calling Methods](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html)."

Comment: That should actually be `def foo(anything = {})`. But it looks like a really strange and unidiomatic way of doing `def foo(**kwargs)`

Comment: It's just based on the most simple way to do it. Over the years Ruby allowed other forms as you note.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you actually changed the signature. `initialize(arg: {})` can be called with no arguments.